# Read txt file with comma in currency

Tags: csv, sas

How to read txt file with comma in currency?

> 123,"Harold Wilson",Acct,01/15/1989,$78,123.
>
> 128,"Julia Child",Food,08/29/1988
>
> 007,"James Bond",Security,02/01/2000,$82,100

Here is my attempt:

```
data employee;
    infile file dsd;
    input 
        id : $3. 
        name : $20. 
        xxx : $ 
        date : mmddyy8.
        cash : dollar8.;
    format 
        date date9.
        cash dollar8.;
run;

proc print data=employee;
run;
```

Comment: As it stands the comma means an extra column. If the figure is quoted `"$78,123"` you should be ok.

Comment: Yes, if you can't change the delimiter _maybe_ you can change that (?) which would solve the problem.

Comment: I cannot do any changes in source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `comma.` informat and changing the delimiter to `;` (or anything other than `,` for that matter) might be a wise choice...

If you can't, here's a workaround:

```
data employee;

  infile datalines dsd truncover;

  informat id $3.
           name $QUOTE20.
           xxx $12.
           date mmddyy10.
           cash1 $6.
           cash2 $6.;

    format date date9.
           cash dollar11.2;

    input id name xxx date cash1 cash2;

    cash = input(cats(cash1, cash2), comma10.);

    drop cash1 cash2;

  datalines;
123,"Harold Wilson",Acct,01/15/1989,$78,123.
128,"Julia Child",Food,08/29/1988
007,"James Bond",Security,02/01/2000,$82,100
;
```

### Results

```
id   name           xxx            date        cash
---  -------------  --------  ---------  ----------
123  Harold Wilson  Acct      15JAN1989  $78,123.00 
128  Julia Child    Food      29AUG1988  . 
007  James Bond     Security  01FEB2000  $82,100.00
```

Comment: I can't change delimeter (it's my source).

Answer (score 2):

Since the problem field is the last one you can just change the delimiter, also need MISSOVER.

```
filename FT15F001 temp;
data employee;
   infile FT15F001 dsd dlm=dlm missover;
      dlm=','; input id:$3. name:$20. xxx:$ date:mmddyy8. @;
      dlm='|'; input  cash:dollar8.;
      format date date9. cash dollar8.;
   parmcards;
123,"Harold Wilson",Acct,01/15/1989,$78,123.
128,"Julia Child",Food,08/29/1988
007,"James Bond",Security,02/01/2000,$82,100
;;;;
   run;
```

Comment: I had no idea you could change the delimiter without a new `infile`.  Cool.